# Struts2 using s:checkbox with c:forEach for selective Trade data records select

Tags: struts2

I have a list of records (Trades) that I need to display onto a JSP Page as tabular data from the Trade POJO and need to get checkbox selections of some of these records as Form POST back to action where I need to check which records were selected. I am doing tabular data display using **c:forEach**.
JSP is as :

```
<s:form id="executeTradesForm" name="executeTradesForm" action="ExeTradeAction">
    <table id="tradesForDisplayTable" border="1" align="left" width="100%"> 
            <tr>
                <s:checkbox name="selAllTradeIds" fieldValue="selAllTradeIds"/>
                <th>Trade ID</th>
                <th>Trade Source</th>
                <th>Currency</th>
                <th>Trade Status</th>
                <th>Trade Date</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>Maturity Date</th>
                <th>Trader Name</th>
                <th>Trade Quantity</th>
                <th>Trade Price</th>
                <th>Buy / Sell</th>
            </tr>

            <c:forEach var="trade" items="${tradesList}" varStatus="stat">
            <tr>
                <td><s:checkbox name="selTradeId" fieldValue="selTradeId"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${trade.tradeId}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${trade.tradeSource}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${trade.currency}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${trade.tradeStatus}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${trade.tradeDate}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${trade.startDate}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${trade.maturityDate}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${trade.traderName}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${trade.tradeQuantity}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${trade.tradePrice.value}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${trade.buySell}" /></td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>

            <s:submit align="left" name="submit" value="Execute Trades" />
```

What is the best approach here in terms of using **s:checkbox** or something else like **s:checkboxlist** .

I need to know if when using **s:checkbox** can we have **fieldValue** attribute as something dynamic like '**checkbox-**' (tradeId being unique and coming from trade.tradeId. How to get that dynamic attribute?

Assuming tradeId is a string value like TRD12345, what will the Action class store it as ?
String[] or boolean array ? (when we use s:checkbox)

*Struts2 docs is wanting and has not given enough examples of using s:checkbox with collections etc.*

Comment: have you tried like `<s:checkbox fieldValue=%{myvalue}/>` where myvalue can be set in action?

Comment: I have List<Trade> exposed to the JSP, I need to have the checkbox fieldValue set to something like chkbox_tradeId within c:forEach.

Comment: if i understand right `tradeid` is a property of `trade`? so if `tradeid` is say 011, all you want checkbox like `<s:checkbox filedvalue=011/>`?

Comment: yes, something dynamic like 'chkbox_trd101' so that when the selected checkbox form data is post back then I can relate the chkbox_trd101 as checkbox of trade with tradeId 101 and get those trades by tradeIds directly from the **ArrayList<Trade>**. Else if I keep them chkbox_i, I will have to somehow relate them to respective tradeIds

Comment: How to get that dynamic attribute?
if you are trying to access dynamic attribute use 
String[] selctedValues =request.getParameterValues("fieldValue").

Comment: @MohanaRaoSV I am aware of the getting the dynamic attribute request.getParameterValues but I was thinking of something like boolean selAllTradeIds; when a checkBox for all is checked or String[] selTradeId for holding values of each respective checkboxes in the tabular data. How that is handled via the Struts2 action class.

Comment: Question can also be put as: Is it possible to get a **dynamic value** like **tradeId** for attribute **fieldValue** in **s:checkbox within a c:forEach** where the c:forEach is iterating over a list of Objects like List<Trade>, if so how? Any pointer or complete code snippet would greatly help

Comment: ultimately, I had to do it using the s:iterator instead of c:forEach (which i think is not a good practice)
`<s:iterator value="tradesList" var="trade">

<s:checkbox name="selAllTradeIds" fieldValue="selAllTradeIds" value="true" theme="simple"  onclick="checkOrUncheckAllCheckBoxes();"/>

<s:checkbox name="selTradeId" fieldValue="%{tradeId}" value="true" theme="simple"/>`

Answer (score 0):

i think that s:checkboxlist is useful in your situation.
you can use it as below:

```
    <s:checkboxlist list="tradesList" name="tradesListSelectedItems"
 listKey="%{tradeId}" listValue="%{youTradeLibelle}">
    </s:checkboxlist>
```

and add in your action class a String property named tradesListSelectedItems that will store the checked values of your trades.
For example, If “trade1” and “trade2” options are checked, the checked values will combine with a comma, **tradesListSelectedItems** = “trade1ID,trade2ID”.